# .keeps showing me an exeption error message that my request data is null ,the return value is a list

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, mvvm

This is the service that i use which gets data from firebase

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Specalist>> GetUser()
        {
            List<Specalist> lstUserInfo = (await firebaseClient
   .Child($"Specalists/{PreferencesConfig.Id}").
           OnceAsync<Specalist >()).Select(item => new Specalist 

           {
               name= item.Object.name,
               type= item.Object.type,
               Passsword = item.Object.Passsword,
               ID = item.Object.ID
           }).ToList();
            return lstUserInfo;

        }
```

And this is the viewmodle :

```
 private ObservableCollection<Specalist> _specalist = new ObservableCollection<Specalist>();
        private ICommand _deletePatient;

        public ObservableCollection<Specalist> Specalists { get => _specalist; set => SetProperty(ref _specalist, value, nameof(Specalists)); }
Specalists = new ObservableCollection<Specalist>((List<Specalist>)await SpecalistService.GetUser());
```

Exception occured while processing the request is what the error msg , how can i fix it!

Comment: are you sure your FB query is returning data?

Comment: The diff between Specalist and Specalists is a typo?

Comment: And if you are sure its a List<T> so you can cast to that why returning IEnumerable<T> in the first place?

Comment: I can't find any breaking point to makesure that my code returns value , i've changed the function in the service file to this  , , , public static async Task<IEnumerable<Specalist>> GetUser()
        {
            var url = await firebaseClient
                     .Child($"Specalists/{PreferencesConfig.Id}").BuildUrlAsync();
            var result = await Helper.Get<List<Specalist>>(url);
            return result;

        } , , , 
and the error now is that it cant deserlize the json object into collcetionlist

Comment: That's mean that the JSON is a single object, not a list, so you need to deserialize it as a single object.